# Equinox Launcher executable

Tags: java, eclipse, equinox

I have an executable file supposedly built by the Eclipse Equinox Launcher

(https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher)

Can the executable contain Java classes? What is contained in the executable, for example `eclipse.exe` on Windows? Is it possible to extract the classes packed in the executable?

Answer (score 2):

There are no classes included in the launcher executable. It just contains code to start the JVM and call the Java code in the jar file specified by the `-startup` option.

The launcher looks for a .ini file with the same name as the launcher in the same directory (so eclipse.ini for eclipse.exe) and reads its contents to determine the start up options.

Comment: So how can we discover which jar it calls to start up and what options are passed to the program, in the case of other Java applications created by Equinox?

Comment: Added note about the ini file to the answer.